# why $f(y_{f_{\varphi}}) = \langle f, f_{\varphi}\rangle ?$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Prove that  every Hilbert space is reflexive.

I found the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3325262/557708)

I have some doubt in  given below  answer marked in red box

[image]

**My thinking** : I think this  sentence ($f_{\varphi} \in \mathcal H^*$. By the RRT, there exists a unique $y_{f_{\varphi}}$ such that for all $f \in \mathcal H^*$, we have $f(y_{f_{\varphi}}) = \langle f, f_{\varphi}\rangle$.)  is **WRONG**

why that given above sentence is wrong ?

**Ans**:  According to RRT  it should be like this $f_{\varphi}(y)=(y,y_{f_{\varphi}})$

**My doubt** :According to **RRT** :If $T$ is a bounded linear functional on a Hilbert space $H$ then
there exists some $g \in H$ such that for every $f \in H$ we have
$T(f) =\langle f, g \rangle $.

Here $\langle f, g \rangle $  contain $f$

If  $f(y_{f_{\varphi}}) = \langle f, f_{\varphi}\rangle$.then where $y_{f_{\varphi}}$ is gone

and $\langle f, f_{\varphi}\rangle$   doesn't contain $y_{f_{\varphi}}$

Therefore  $f(y_{f_{\varphi}}) \neq \langle f, f_{\varphi}\rangle$

So  im not getting why  $f(y_{f_{\varphi}}) = \langle f, f_{\varphi}\rangle ?$.

Comment: In the original post, my goal is not merely to prove that Hilbert spaces are reflexive, it is also to explain the particular proof and the pivotal step
$$
\hat{y}_{f_\varphi}(f)= f(y_{f_\varphi})=\langle\,y_{f_\varphi},y_f\rangle=\langle\,f,f_\varphi\rangle=\varphi(f).
$$
My step is mathematically correct, but it is not a direct application of the RRT as I had claimed.

Comment: oks  thanks for clarification@Benn Grossmann actually ..i was  misunderstood  that it's a direct application  of RRT

Comment: I definitely should have been clearer. I'm editing my original answer now

Comment: See the latest edit [to my post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3325262/81360).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes im right.
It should be  like this

Now, $f_{\varphi} \in \mathcal H^*$. By the RRT, there exists a unique $y_{f}$ such that for all $f \in \mathcal H^*$, we  have

$$\ f(y_{f_\varphi})=\langle\,y_{f_\varphi},y_f\rangle$$ for all $y_{f_\varphi} \in \mathcal H$

Using the RRT two times  we have  $||y_f||=||f_{\varphi}||$  and $||f||=||y_{f_\varphi}||$

Therefore $f(y_{f_{\varphi}}) = \langle f, f_{\varphi}\rangle$.

Comment: What do you mean by "for all $y_{f_{\varphi}} \in \mathcal H$"? What is the connection between $y_{f_{\varphi}}$ and $f_{\varphi}$?

Comment: $y_{f_{\varphi}} \in\mathcal{H} $  and $y_{f_{\varphi}}$ is almost similar to $y \in \mathcal{H}$      ...
  for $2$ nd question  connection between ${y}_{f_\varphi}$ and ${f_\varphi}$
$\hat{y}_{f_\varphi}(f)= f(y_{f_\varphi})$  Here $f_{\varphi} \in \mathcal{H}^*$ and $\hat{y}_{f_\varphi} \in  \mathcal{H}^{* *}$

Comment: correct me  if im wrong @BenGrossmann

Comment: I can't tell if you're wrong because I can't understand what you wrote

Comment: Here $y_{f_\varphi}=y$  for all $y\in \mathcal H$ . And  connection between $y_{f_\varphi}$ and $ {f_\varphi}$ is that $ {f_\varphi}$ is taken as unique  while  $y_{f_\varphi}=y$ is for all $y\in \mathcal H$

Comment: None of what you just said makes sense if I interpret it literally. If $y_{f_\varphi} = y$ for all $y \in \mathcal H$, that means that for any pair of elements $y_1,y_2 \in \mathcal H$, we have $y_1 = y_{\varphi} = y_2$, which is to say that $\mathcal H$ contains exactly one element. I don't think this is what you meant. For the second sentence, what you've written does not describe a connection between $y_{f_{\varphi}}$ and $f_{\varphi}$. In other words, If I replace every $y_{f_{\varphi}}$ with a $z$, nothing about your comment or proof seems to change.